# How to include maven dependencies in Cordova command line build?

Tags: android, maven, cordova

I have a Cordova project which uses maven to manage dependencies, when I do "cordova build" in command line, it cannot find the maven depencencies causing compile to fail.

How to include maven dependencies in Cordova command line build? Any pointer is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/06/29/using-phonegap-build-with-maven.html Let me know!

Comment: thanks for the link, it seems a lot of work. But instead, I gave up on cordova build and went with maven build only, added the cordova-android.jar to my maven local repo, things are all good now.

Comment: Perfect...Good for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `.gradle` files `CordovaLib/cordova.gradle`, `CordovaLib/build.gradle` via `gradle` but to do it in maven I found a different approach to be efficient.

`git clone http://github.com/my_maven_repo`
`cd` into it and look for the `pom.xml` file
go to the `<build><plugins>` tags and with the existing plugins add these 2:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id><phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

now, go to terminal and type the command `mvn clean compile assembly:single`.
You'll see the new `JAR` with dependencies in the `/packageName/target/` as a compiled `JAR` - now you just import it to Cordova or any Android/Java project.

Hope it helps